# Split semicolon-delimited column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to split a column, in SQL, into multiple columns.

My data looks like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3  
ABC     | 123     | User7;User9  
nbm     | qre     | User1;User2;User3  
POI     | kjh     | User1;User4;User5;User9
```

I need to split the Column3 into 4 new columns - each column containing the first "User".  Each value within this column is separated by a semi-colon.  One of the problems I have is that Column3 can have any number of users listed (all separated by semi-colons), so I don't know how many "new" columns I would need added.

The final output would need to look like:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | NewColumn1 | NewColumn2 | ETC.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need the users in the same table? Why not separate them out into another table, then create a link table to join them? That way you don't need to worry so much how many users there's going to be...

Comment: Are you actually wanting to modify the table structure containing the data, or is it just for display purposes?

Comment: The reason you are having a problem is because your data is not properly normalized. You first have to split that delimited list into something usable. Then you will need a dynamic crosstab or pivot to generate the dynamic columns you require.

Comment: delimited strings are a BIG no no.  You should fix your data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the fact that this is bad design here is a solution:

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
declare @tbl TABLE(Column1 VARCHAR(15),Column2 VARCHAR(15),Column3 VARCHAR(150));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('ABC','123','User7;User9')  
,('nbm','qre','User1;User2;User3')  
,('POI','kjh','User1;User4;User5;User9');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT Column1,Column2,CAST('<x>'+REPLACE(Column3,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AS Col3Splitted
    FROM @tbl
) 
SELECT Column1,Column2,Col3Splitted
                      ,Col3Splitted.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Column4
                      ,Col3Splitted.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Column5
                      ,Col3Splitted.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS Column6
                      ,Col3Splitted.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS Column7
                      /*Add as many as you need*/
FROM Splitted
```

Following the discussion with @SeanLang I add this dynamic approach. It will count the highest number of semicolons in Column3 and build the statement above dynamically.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (Column1 VARCHAR(15),Column2 VARCHAR(15),Column3 VARCHAR(150));
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
 ('ABC','123','User7;User9')  
,('nbm','qre','User1;User2;User3')  
,('POI','kjh','User1;User4;User5;User9');

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)=
'WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT Column1,Column2,CAST(''<x>''+REPLACE(Column3,'';'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' AS XML) AS Col3Splitted
    FROM #tbl
) 
SELECT Column1,Column2';
DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
WHILE @counter<=(SELECT MAX(LEN(Column3) - LEN(REPLACE(Column3, ';', ''))) from #tbl)
BEGIN
    SET @counter=@counter+1;
    SET @sql=@sql+',Col3Splitted.value(''x[' +  CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'',''varchar(max)'') AS Column' + CAST(@counter+3 AS VARCHAR(10));
END
SET @sql=@sql+ ' FROM Splitted;';

EXEC (@sql);  

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

Comment: This works but isn't going to support the unknown number of columns requirement. For that it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: @SeanLange, Yes and no... You can add the expected max number of columns, they will return with NULL if empty. The design is bad enough. This would - at least - come back with a definit structure ;-)

Comment: Agreed that the design stinks worse than 1,000 year old eggs but the OP did state they don't know how many columns will be returned. Your approach is not dynamic in that regard.

Comment: @SeanLange, in my point of view a dynamic approach makes it even worse. With a definit number of columns there's at least one secure thing you can stick to...

Comment: Often times we are unable to change the structure and have to make it work with the awful stuff presented to us. And sometimes this requires a dynamic number of columns based on the data.

Comment: @SeanLange, to make it "dynamic" one could find the max count of semicolons and build this statement dynamically just by repeating the lines beginning with `Col3Splitted.value...`

Comment: @SeanLange, This would be the trick to count the max number of semicolons: `select MAX(len(Column3) - len(replace(Column3, ';', ''))) from @tbl;`

Comment: I have to say that changing the code everytime you want to run it is nothing like being dynamic. That is just changing the static code to a new set of rules.

Comment: @SeanLange, this is not what I meant... I thought about a dynamic generation of my statement with a dynamically created repetition of the middle lines and a final EXEC. That means real "dynamic SQL". But this discussion is quite academic as we do not know what exactly the OP needs...

Comment: Somewhat academic but the OP did state "so I don't know how many 'new' columns I would need added." That is a pretty clear indication it needs to be dynamic. The only point I was really making is that your fine example is only the first part. It is a great example of using xml to split delimited strings.

Comment: @SeanLange, btw: You speak about splitting strings. Your example uses the function dbo.DelimitedSplit8K which is not part of your answer...

Comment: @Shnugo This worked. How can I insert the results into a TEMP table for more comparison?  Thank you.

Comment: @RyanWB, that's easy, luckyly: You've to add just `INTO tableName` before the `FROM Splitted`. So: If you want to create a new table called "MyTable" (be aware to affect the right database! just change the last line to `INTO MyTable FROM Splitted;` The structure is created automatically... (read here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Comment: @RyanWB, one more hint: If you want to do this more often, you must either `DROP` the created table before you run this code, or you must change the target table's name. Otherwise you'll get a runtime error due to "object already exists"...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will be 100% dynamic. It will produce any number of columns based solely on the data it finds. The prevailing method for this around SO is a dynamic pivot. I prefer a dynamic crosstab as I find the syntax less obtuse and it has a slight benefit from a performance standpoint too. :)

Here is an article which explains this methodology very well. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Also, I am using the DelimitedSplit8K function originally penned by Jeff Moden and improved over time through the community. You can read about it and find the code for it here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something;

create table #something
(
    Column1 varchar(5)
    , Column2 varchar(5)
    , Column3 varchar(50)
);

insert #something
select 'ABC', '123', 'User7;User9' union all
select 'nbm', 'qre', 'User1;User2;User3' union all
select 'POI', 'kjh', 'User1;User4;User5;User9';

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 'with orderedResults as
(
    select s.Column1
        , s.Column2
        , x.Item
        , x.ItemNumber
    from #something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(Column3, '';'') x
)

select Column1
    , Column2
';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';

    WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + ', MAX(Case when ItemNumber = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then Item end) as Subject' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <=
(
    select top 1 COUNT(*)
    from #something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(Column3, ';') x
    group by Column1
    Order by COUNT(*) desc
);

declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from orderedResults group by Column1, Column2 order by Column1, Column2';

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;

select @SqlToExecute;
--uncomment the following line when you are sure this is what you want to execute.
--exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQl below code can be used. This is just a sample code

```
@num_Column3 := 1 + LENGTH(@Column3) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@Column3, '|', '')) AS num_Column3
,IF(@num_Column3 > 0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Column3)), '|', 1), '|', -1), '') AS RC_user
```